# How To Iterate Though Nodes Added To TreeView Using a Derives TreeNode Instance

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a `TreeView` control in which I need to add some nodes passing a string to the `Add()` method, and add some nodes passing a derived `TreeNode` class instance to the `Add()` method.

I'm trying to see which leaf nodes are checked and I just can't figure out how to iterate through the nodes that are derived `TreeNode` class (`EmojiNode`) instances shown below.

```cs
TreeNode groupnode = EmojisTreeView.Nodes.Add("Group Name");

EmojiNode emojiNode = new EmojiNode(subgroupEmojiName, unicodeEndStr, emojiConvertResultStr);
int groupsubemojinode = groupsubnode.Nodes.Add(emojiNode);

foreach (var node in EmojisTreeView.Nodes.OfType<EmojiNode>())
{
   // count is 0
}

    public class EmojiNode : TreeNode
    {
        public string emojiName;
        public string emojiValue;
        public string emojiConvertedResultStr;

        public EmojiNode(string emojiName, string emojiValue, string emojiConvertedResultStr)
        {
            this.emojiName = emojiName;
            this.emojiValue = emojiValue;
            this.emojiConvertedResultStr = emojiConvertedResultStr;

            this.Text = this.emojiConvertedResultStr + " " + this.emojiName;
        }

        public EmojiNode(string emojiName)
        {
            this.emojiName = emojiName;

            this.Text = this.emojiName;
        }

        public string getEmojiName()
        {
            return this.emojiName;
        }

        public string getEmojiValue()
        {
            return this.emojiValue;
        }

        public string getEmojiConvertedResultStr()
        {
            return this.emojiConvertedResultStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `foreach (var node in EmojisTreeView.Nodes) ...` if the `Nodes` collection has both types. If so, you can also get the derived type `foreach (var node in EmojisTreeView.Nodes.OfType<EmojiNode>()) ...`

Comment: Also consider using a recursive function to iterate over all the branches of the tree. See an example of that function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775440/10216583).

Comment: Paste the class please..

Comment: `public class EmojiNode : TreeNode
    {
        public string emojiName;
        public string emojiValue;
        public string emojiConvertedResultStr;

        public EmojiNode(string emojiName, string emojiValue, string emojiConvertedResultStr)
        {
            this.emojiName = emojiName;
            this.emojiValue = emojiValue;
            this.emojiConvertedResultStr = emojiConvertedResultStr;

            this.Text = this.emojiConvertedResultStr + " " + this.emojiName;
        }
    }
`

Comment: I can't because Add(emojiNode) returns an Int and I need it to return EmojiNode for a specific reason. I edited the question to show the EmojiNode class

Comment: You can: `var groupnode = EmojisTreeView.Nodes.Add("Group Name") as EmojiNode;`

Comment: Tried `var groupnode = EmojisTreeView.Nodes.Add("Group Name") as EmojiNode;` and groupnode is null. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry bud. Can't  without understanding what you are trying to do. Pieces are missing. For example, what is `groupsubnode` ? If you could elaborate more, maybe a screenshot to illustrate the desired output, will help a lot to understand and maybe we could suggest better approaches.